# Преобразовать JSON строку в объект c#

Tags: c#, json

Есть строка JSON:

```
{
  "ICAO": "EGLC",
  "IATA": "LCY",
  "name": "London City",
  "region": "United Kingdom",
  "elevation": 19,
  "lat": 51.5052306,
  "lon": 0.05517525,
  "magneticVariation": -0.7303151023049803,
  "timezone": {
    "name": "Europe/London",
    "offset": 3600
  },
  "times": {
    "sunrise": "2015-08-04T04:28:42.115Z",
    "sunset": "2015-08-04T19:45:39.086Z",
    "dawn": "2015-08-04T03:48:43.656Z",
    "dusk": "2015-08-04T20:25:37.545Z"
  },
  "runwayCount": 1,
  "runways": [
    {
      "ident": "09",
      "width": 97.998687813,
      "length": 4930.643052114,
      "bearing": 92.89,
      "surface": "Concrete",
      "thresholdOffset": 322.014436185,
      "overrunLength": 164.009186601,
      "ends": [
        {
          "ident": "09",
          "lat": 51.50557275,
          "lon": 0.0443354
        },
        {
          "ident": "27",
          "lat": 51.50488846,
          "lon": 0.0660151
        }
      ],
      "navaids": [
        {
          "ident": "ILST",
          "type": "LOC-ILS",
          "lat": 51.504842,
          "lon": 0.067503,
          "airport": "EGLC",
          "runway": "09",
          "frequency": 111150000,
          "slope": null,
          "bearing": 92.91,
          "name": "ILS-cat-I",
          "elevation": 19,
          "range": 18
        },
        {
          "ident": "ILST",
          "type": "GS",
          "lat": 51.506011,
          "lon": 0.047403,
          "airport": "EGLC",
          "runway": "09",
          "frequency": 111150000,
          "slope": 5.05,
          "bearing": 92.903,
          "name": "GS",
          "elevation": 35,
          "range": 10
        },
        {
          "ident": "ILST",
          "type": "DME",
          "lat": 51.505847,
          "lon": 0.055411,
          "airport": "EGLC",
          "runway": "09",
          "frequency": 111150000,
          "slope": null,
          "bearing": null,
          "name": "DME-ILS",
          "elevation": 48,
          "range": 18
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ident": "27",
      "width": 97.998687813,
      "length": 4930.643052114,
      "bearing": 272.91,
      "surface": "Concrete",
      "thresholdOffset": 243.011811393,
      "overrunLength": 279.00262509600003,
      "ends": [
        {
          "ident": "27",
          "lat": 51.50488846,
          "lon": 0.0660151
        },
        {
          "ident": "09",
          "lat": 51.50557275,
          "lon": 0.0443354
        }
      ],
      "navaids": [
        {
          "ident": "ILSR",
          "type": "LOC-ILS",
          "lat": 51.505642,
          "lon": 0.042125,
          "airport": "EGLC",
          "runway": "27",
          "frequency": 111150000,
          "slope": null,
          "bearing": 272.892,
          "name": "ILS-cat-I",
          "elevation": 19,
          "range": 18
        },
        {
          "ident": "ILSR",
          "type": "GS",
          "lat": 51.505514,
          "lon": 0.06335,
          "airport": "EGLC",
          "runway": "27",
          "frequency": 111150000,
          "slope": 5.5,
          "bearing": 272.903,
          "name": "GS",
          "elevation": 35,
          "range": 10
        },
        {
          "ident": "ILSR",
          "type": "DME",
          "lat": 51.505794,
          "lon": 0.054425,
          "airport": "EGLC",
          "runway": "27",
          "frequency": 111150000,
          "slope": null,
          "bearing": null,
          "name": "DME-ILS",
          "elevation": 48,
          "range": 18
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "frequencies": [
    {
      "type": "REC",
      "frequency": 136350000,
      "name": "City Information"
    },
    {
      "type": "GND",
      "frequency": 121820000,
      "name": "City Ground"
    },
    {
      "type": "TWR",
      "frequency": 118070000,
      "name": "City Tower"
    },
    {
      "type": "TWR",
      "frequency": 118400000,
      "name": "City Tower"
    },
    {
      "type": "APP",
      "frequency": 132700000,
      "name": "City Approach"
    }
  ],
  "weather": {
    "METAR": "EGLC 042150Z AUTO 23009KT 200V270 9999 NCD 17/10 Q1016",
    "TAF": null
  }
}
```

Как ее преобразовать в объект в C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помещаем наш json в буфер обмена. В Visual Studio идем в меню View - Paste Special - Paste JSON As Classes. Студия распарсит ваш json и сформирует на его основе структуру классов:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string ICAO { get; set; }
    public string IATA { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public int elevation { get; set; }
    public float lat { get; set; }
    ... // и т.д.
```

При необходимости можете подправить полученные классы - изменить типы свойств, например.

В Solution Explorer кликаем правой кнопкой на References, выбираем Manage NuGet Packages... С вкладки Browse подключаем последнюю версию пакета Newtonsoft.Json.

Возвращаемся к коду. Помещаем наш json в строку:

```
string json = @"...";
```

Все двойные кавычки нужно экранировать такой же кавычкой, либо заменить на одинарные кавычки (апострофы).

Парсим:

```
var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Всё, теперь можно обращаться к свойствам объекта, например:

```
Console.WriteLine(rootobject.weather.METAR);
```

---

[Здесь в документации лежит подобный пример](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ. Вечером напишу - получилось или нет =) А если не трудно, можете посдсказать, некоторые параметры в этой строке (там просто много разной информации каждый раз приходят) иногда могут быть равны null, есть ли какой-нибудь способ упрощенной проверки на null, или для каждого параметра это проверять? Спасибо)

Comment: Для начала почитайте про операторы `?.`, `?[]` и `??`, возможно найдете ответ. Если нет - отдельным вопросом подробно описываете что вам нужно в случае получения `null` - будем думать.

Comment: Нужно числовые литералы обнулить (0), а строковые представить в виде пустой строки ("") Спасибо, почитаю)

Comment: Вам подойдет оператор `??`. Читайте.

Comment: Спасибо, ознакомлюсь)